# why when I post a form element I get undefined index error?

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

I am retrieving some data from the database and insert them in to the table using the following code . I am trying to make each row one form and once the user click the button I want to send the information to `sub.php` to store it in DB.Currently the problem is when I post the info i get undefined value . 
Here is my code :

```
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo '<form  method="Post" action="sub.php" ><tr>
                                            <td class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">'
                                                .$row["name"] .
                                            '</td>
                                            <td class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">'
                                                .$row["course_name"] .
                                            '</td>
                                            <td class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">'
                                                .$row["course_lec"] .
                                            '</td>
                                            <td class="text-center"  style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">'
                                                .$row["course_sem"] .
                                            '</td>
                                            <td class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;color:white;" >
                                                <select  style="background-color: #222222; border: none; name="q1">
                                                 <option value="0">0</option> 
                                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                                  <option value="6">6</option>
                                                  <option value="7">7</option>
                                                  <option value="8">8</option>
                                                  <option value="9">9</option>
                                                  <option value="10">10</option>

                                            </select>   

                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">
                                            <select  style="background-color: #222222; border: none; name="q2">
                                                 <option value="0">0</option> 
                                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                                  <option value="6">6</option>
                                                  <option value="7">7</option>
                                                  <option value="8">8</option>
                                                  <option value="9">9</option>
                                                  <option value="10">10</option>

                                            </select>    
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center"  style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">
                                                   <select  style="background-color: #222222; border: none; name="q3">
                                                 <option value="0">0</option> 
                                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                                  <option value="6">6</option>
                                                  <option value="7">7</option>
                                                  <option value="8">8</option>
                                                  <option value="9">9</option>
                                                  <option value="10">10</option>

                                            </select>   
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">
                                                   <select  style="background-color: #222222; border: none; name="q4">
                                                 <option value="0">0</option> 
                                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                                  <option value="6">6</option>
                                                  <option value="7">7</option>
                                                  <option value="8">8</option>
                                                  <option value="9">9</option>
                                                  <option value="10">10</option>

                                            </select>   
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center" class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;color:white;">
                                                   <select  style="background-color: #222222; border: none; name="q5" >
                                                 <option value="0">0</option> 
                                                  <option value="1">1</option>
                                                  <option value="2">2</option>
                                                  <option value="3">3</option>
                                                  <option value="4">4</option>
                                                  <option value="5">5</option>
                                                  <option value="6">6</option>
                                                  <option value="7">7</option>
                                                  <option value="8">8</option>
                                                  <option value="9">9</option>
                                                  <option value="10">10</option>

                                            </select>   
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center" class="text-center" style="border-color:yellow;">
                                                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" >submit</button>
                                            </td>

                                           </form> ' 

                                            ;
                             }

                    }
```

and in sub.php I have :

```
<?php


include ("conn.php") ; 
session_start();


$selectOption = $_POST["q1"];




?>
```

and for better understanding I've put the image there too 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Most probably the select box with the name q1 haven't selected before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a closing quote on your `style=""` attribute in your select tag:

```
<select  style="background-color: #222222; border: none; name="q1">
```

Hence the field isn't getting named `q1`, fix it like this:

```
<select  style="background-color: #222222; border: none;" name="q1">
```

Same goes for your other questions.

Answer (score -1):

you may have to try :

```
if(!empty $_POST["q1"])
{
    $selectOption = $_POST["q1"];
}
```

Test existing variables to be sure you won't get an index error. 
Hope it was helping!

Comment: This is invalid syntax.